# Хостинг исчез . Что делать?

Tags: хостинг

Я создала сайты и внесла их на хостинг. Работал в районе где то полгода год правда один раз перестал работать хостинг, но написав в техподдержку мне ответили, и все вернулось на круги свои. 
Сейчас заблокировали в техподдержке (это в контакте). А также не доступен их телефон и почта, сайт хостинга не работает уже четвёртые сутки, ну и соотвественно мой размещённый на данном хостинга. Помимо того, что бэкап немного старенький, то есть просто плюнуть и взять другой хостинг, там был оплачен следующий год пользования хостингом. Подскажите, что мне делать? Как вернуть свой сайт 
UPd если кто-то знает контакты merahost.net отзовитесь, пожалуйста 
Вы спасёте пусть не глобальный, но ценный ресурс

Comment: https://www.nic.ru/whois/?searchWord=merahost.net по ссылке Вы можете найти информацию, касающуюся владельца домена, в том числе и контактные данные(мобильный номер / email)

Comment: Вы дали номер салона красоты;)

Comment: Кстати, в контакте такого объявления я не увидела..

Comment: Шёл 2018 год, а люди всё ещё не делали регулярные бэкапы...

Comment: Допустим бекэап будет немного старый обидно досадно но что же теперь;( но как вернуть деньги????

Comment: Подскажите адрес группы партнёрки, плиз! Группу merahost.net удалили, телефон недоступен

Comment: Походу админы сайта merahost.net мошенники !!! Все номера принадлежат салону красоты!!! Причём не важно какой городской или мобильный!!!поэтому мне просто необходима группа партнёры!! Подскажите, плиз

Comment: Нашла их партнера.. но боюсь что там тоже будет пусто

Comment: Вот вот вот как понять, где админы хостингом нормальные ребята, а где мошенники?